# I set getAuth to auth in my html script tag and I am trying to use it in my auth.js but I keep getting an error auth is not defined. How fix?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**Here is my index.html.**
Oh, and yes, my script tag is inside my body tag.

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    import { getAuth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-auth.js';
    import { getFirestore } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-firestore.js';

    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "HIDDEN FOR THIS POST",
      authDomain: "case-study---login-system.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "case-study---login-system",
      storageBucket: "case-study---login-system.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "HIDDEN FOR THIS POST",
      appId: "HIDDEN FOR THIS POST",
      measurementId: "HIDDEN FOR THIS POST"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

    // make auth and firestone references 
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const db = getFirestore(app);
  </script>

<!-- Compiled and minified (Materialized)JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script-->
<script src="static/auth.js"></script>
<script src="static/index.js"></script>
```

**Here is my auth.js**

```
 // Signup 
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // get user info
    const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value;
    const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;
    // sign up the user
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(cred => {
        console.log(cred);
    }); 
});
```

**The error I keep getting to the console is:**

auth.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: auth is not defined
at HTMLFormElement.

Answer (score 1):

When you add `type="module"` to a `<script>` tag, it all variables are in the module's own scope - not the global scope like regular `<script>` tags.

To access `auth` from `static/auth.js`, you will need to add `auth` to the global scope:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
window.analytics = getAnalytics(app);

// make auth and firestone references 
window.auth = getAuth(app);
window.db = getFirestore(app);
```

While this works for simple projects and testing, you should consider moving to using a module bundler like Rollup or WebPack as the [documentation recommends](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/module-bundling).