# Firebase not creating users

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My firebase isn't creating users and it isn't giving any errors. I have been trying to fix this for about 25 hours i think... My code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress HtmlRequiredLangAttribute -->
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style/login.css">
    <script src="src/js/login.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Project Cross Comm!</title>


    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.16.0/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.16.0/firebase-auth.js";


        // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "private",
            authDomain: "private",
            databaseURL: "private",
            projectId: "private",
            storageBucket: "private",
            messagingSenderId: "private",
            appId: "private,
            measurementId: "private",
        };
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth(app);


    //on click of button with id register, run function register
        document.getElementById("register1").addEventListener("click", register);


        function register() {

            const email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;

            createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    // ...
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                    // ..
                });
        }
        function login() {

            const email = document.getElementById("emailreauth").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("log-pass").value;
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    // Signed in
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    // ...
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    const errorCode = error.code;
                    const errorMessage = error.message;
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form" id="register">
            <img src="src/IMG/profile.png" alt="profile">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <input type="text" id="usernameinput" name="createUsername" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="email" id="emailinput" value="" placeholder="example@example.com" name="createEmail">
            <input type="password" id="passinput" value="" placeholder="password" name="createPass">
            <button id="register1">create</button>
            <p class="message">Already registered? <a onclick="gotologin()">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form" id="login">
            <img src="src/IMG/profile.png" alt="profile">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="email" placeholder="username" id="emailreauth" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="passreauth" id="log-pass" value="" />
            <button id="signin" onclick="login()">login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a onclick="gotoregister()">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <button id=mystat onclick="status01()">CLICK me to GET Status</button>

    <button id=mystat onclick="logout()">CLICK me to logout </button>


</body>


<footer>
    <noscript>Man, sucks for you! We only support modern, functioning browsers. Maybe you should get JavaScript
    </noscript>
</footer>

</html>
```

I have tried searching the internet. Using every type of import. using a seperate file, older versions. Recreating youtube tutorials. Copying official code. I'm out of idea's

Comment: hmm.. seems it has split my code a bit weird.. But i think everyone gets what it was meant to look like haha :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75226182). You have the same issue of not adding `login` and `register` to the global scope.

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your register button. Right now it submits the form and reloads the page

Comment: You should also use `addEventListener()` for `login` the same way you do for `register`

Comment: Omg tysm... The type="button" fixed it hahaha